# how to track and resolve "cannot load [xy] into server: undefined symbol" in apache2

Tags: apache-2.4, svn, ubuntu-14.04

I just recently ran into an error

`apache2: Syntax error on line 140 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax error on line 2 of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/dav_svn_authz.load: Cannot load /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_authz_svn.so into server: /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_authz_svn.so: undefined symbol: ap_hook_force_authn`

Doing some research on the web, I found a huge amount of possible fixes to this problem. Also I understand, that this might be caused by:

- apache2 loading mods in wrong order
- libraries being out of date
- old/incompatible versions of libapache2-svn, svn itself..

I already tried a dirty trick in renaming the authz_svn.load file to dav_svn_authz.load, changing the load order, but to no avail. Since I ran into this problem on an ubuntu machine running plesk in a productive environment, I don't want to fumble around. Hence the question:

What would be an elaborate way to track down the reason for this error?

Comment: Elaborate? I would start with the simple ones. By far the most likely explanation is the module and apache server are different versions. Check the provenance of the .so file you have - did it come from the same distribution that your apache came from? is it the same package version? Can you update to a consistent config?